# Что останется при вас или у вас?

Tags: предлоги

«Что останется при вас». Верно ли употребление «при»?

Answer (score 2):

**Что останется при вас / у вас.**

У вас ― это вообще, а при вас ― в данный момент или  рядом с вами.

Примеры:

― Я шучу. **Деньги при вас?** ― Допустим, но я заплачу только на месте. [Наталья Александрова. Последний ученик да Винчи (2010)]

...**останется при вас навеки**; с тем вы и умрёте, не передав никому, может быть самого-то главного из вашей идеи" [VIII, 328]. [Ю. М. Лотман. Символ в системе культуры (1982-1992)]

Comment: «Если за долги забирают имущество, важно знать, что останется при вас» неуместно такое употребление?

Comment: Если перейти на деловой стиль, то надо задать такой вопрос: что останется в вашей собственности? А "при вас" - это то же самое, только в разговорной речи. А вот выражение "останется у вас", как мне кажется,  в меньшей степени  затрагивает тему собственности, оно более неопределенное. Останется у вас, но ваше ли оно?

Comment: Предлог у 2. Указывает на владельца, обладателя чего-, кого-л. или носителя каких-нибудь качеств, свойств, состояний. Предлог  при 5. Указывает на лицо, имеющее в наличии что-л.; у.